# Wait until response from API to execute javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a site which shows the weather for the next three days of a previously specified city (default city or city searched using a form) --> http://agustin-suarez.com/demos/yield/index.html

I use the API of OpenWeatherMap.org to do so. I am also using Google Tag Manager to send some events to Google Analytics which save the results obtained in the website. This is the code for the Macro (custom html tag):

```
<script>

(function($) {
    $(window).bind("load", function() {

     var climaMañana = document.getElementById("reservar1Clima").value;
     var precioMañana = document.getElementById("reservar1Precio").value;
     var climaPasadoMañana = document.getElementById("reservar2Clima").value;
     var precioPasadoMañana = document.getElementById("reservar2Precio").value;
     var climaDosDias = document.getElementById("reservar3Clima").value;
     var precioDosDias = document.getElementById("reservar3Precio").value;          

        dataLayer.push({'event': 'climaMañana', 'eventLabelMañana': climaMañana, 'eventValueMañana': precioMañana});
        dataLayer.push({'event': 'climaPasadoMañana', 'eventLabelPasadoMañana': climaPasadoMañana, 'eventValuePasadoMañana': precioPasadoMañana});
        dataLayer.push({'event': 'climaDosDias', 'eventLabelDosDias': climaDosDias, 'eventValueDosDias': precioDosDias});

    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

It works really good 90% of the time, but if the API spends more time than usual to send the response, Google Tag Manager is sending those events anyway with blank values for the variables, which is not optimal for keeping data quality in Google Analytics.

Any suggestion for making Google Tag Manager to wait until all variables are populated?

Comment: Show the code where the weather API is queried. You need to execute the Analytics code (above) in a callback of that after the weather data is received.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp here is the code: http://pastebin.com/m9apFKRM The problem about excuting this code after the weather data is recieved is that Google Tag Manager (which fires the code above) have to be loaded just after the <body>. My knowledge of javascript is not the best :) so I don't know if the "dataLayer.push({'event': 'climaMañana'..." part is javascript or google tag manager specific, but GTM waits for this to fire the final event which populate all the data into Analytics. I will try puting this code at the end of the javascript as you suggest (I lose anything doing it) Thx!

Comment: @MarcellFülöp it works thx. I have tested it 15-20 times and in Analytics everything seems to look fine. Even after waiting 5-10 seconds for the weather data, the event is sent just after the site is correctly populated. I have yet even the possibility to not push this data if someone searched for a wrong city or if OpenWeatherMap is down, because I can tell the script not doing it if the variables are empty. Thx very much!